# How can i duplicate a whole nintex form + workflow function

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, nintex-workflow

I just took over this entire sharepoint project over from an ex-staff and I am supposed to bring his entire nintex form over to another site. However, I do know any methods or functions to do so.

This form in particular is a nintex form, that upon submission, would consolidate all responses into a custom list which can be then be exported into excel format.

The workflow works where after each submission of the form, an email will be sent to the moderator.

I am extremely new into sharepoint and I do not know all the correct terms so please guide me well.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

In order do do this, Nintex Workflow and Forms, both have an option of export/import, as you can see:

[image: Export/Import Nintex Forms]

[image: Export/Import Nintex Workflow]

So, after the export you will get a file with the extension .nwp(Workflow) and .nfp(Form). Then, in the other site that you refer, you just need to create a Workflow or a Form and select import with that file.

Note: If you are new in Sharepoint/Nintex, notice that any List, Document Library, etc. where the form/workflow is associated will need to be as it is, in the old site, otherwise you'll need to make some changes to the Workflow or Form to include the new site information, such as list column names (per example).

I hope that this answer could help you, have a nice day.